# Have no orders for time, but need to show it

Tags: postgresql

I need to create a metric which shows how many orders was created in every hour for a specific day of the week. But there is some time with any records in DB. But I still need to show this time.

```sql
select count(id),
       date_trunc('hour', created_at at time zone 'US/Pacific')::time as "time"
from "order"
where to_char(created_at, 'day') like '%wed%'
group by date_trunc('hour', created_at at time zone 'US/Pacific')::time
```

In result, I have something like this

count,time

| 6  | 00:00:00 |
+--+------------+

| 3  | 01:00:00 |
+--+------------+

| 4  | 03:00:00 |
+--+------------+

| 5  | 05:00:00 |
+--+------------+

But need this

count,time

| 6  | 00:00:00 |
+--+------------+

| 3  | 01:00:00 |
+--+------------+

| 0  | 02:00:00 |
+--+------------+

| 4  | 03:00:00 |
+--+------------+

| 0  | 04:00:00 |
+--+------------+

| 5  | 05:00:00 |
+--+------------+

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a calendar table containing all possible times, and then join with that:

```
WITH times AS (
    SELECT '00:00:00'::time AS timeval UNION ALL
    SELECT '01:00:00'::time UNION ALL
    SELECT '02:00:00'::time UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT '23:00:00'::time
)

SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS count,
    t.timeval
FROM times t
LEFT JOIN "order" o
    ON t.timeval = date_trunc('hour', o.created_at at time zone 'US/Pacific')::time AND
    to_char(o.created_at, 'day') LIKE '%wed%'
GROUP BY
    t.timeval;
```

If you don't want to report the full 24 hours, then just modify the `times` CTE to include only the hours you do want.

Comment: I doubt that.  Setup a demo and paste the link here, with actual data.

Comment: Are you serious? Link for actual DB?

Comment: Please [create a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk), with actual data, and paste the link here. My answer should be working, I think.

Comment: It can't work, because of join. How can you join on date_trunc that not exist in DB?

Comment: Do you understand how left joins work?  _Every_ time interval in the CTE is _guaranteed_ to appear in the output, even if it matches to no records in your table.  You might have been using an inner join, which in fact would not work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `SELECT (generate_series(0, 23) * interval '1 hour')::time AS timeval` would save you some writing.

Comment: @Cornholio That would assume that I actually know Postgres, which I don't :-) ... BTW, are you a Beavis & Butthead fan?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen this conversation is absolutely about nothing if you think I am so stupid to lie that it does not work. Sorry to take your time, but alas, it does not work. If it worked, with any of joins, this question would not exist.

Comment: If you can't show me any sample data, then unfortunately I can't offer any additional help over what I have put into the above answer.

Comment: @Cornholio this was my version of a solution but still don't work. And I really don't understand why.

Comment: Wait...I take back what I said.  Try moving your `WHERE` condition to check for Wednesday to the `ON` clause.  This might partially explain why the answer does not work for you.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen thank you for the idea. I completely forgot about at time zone 'US/Pacific' at WHERE condition.

Comment: @ZhenyaVasilinenko This answer works for me in a similar table. You could just replace all the `SELECT '00:00:00' ...` in the common table expression with my code.

Comment: @Zhenya Next time you ask a SQL question here, remember that sample data is like a picture as compared to a thousand words (did we actually get close to that here?).  Sample data, and maybe a demo, takes away so much uncertainty in a SQL question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not this :

```
select count(id),
       date_trunc('hour', created_at at time zone 'US/Pacific')::time as "time"
from "order"
where to_char(created_at, 'day') like '%wed%' and count(id)=0 or count(id)!=0
group by date_trunc('hour', created_at at time zone 'US/Pacific')::time
```

Comment: Because you can't use aggregate functions in WHERE in postgresql

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't see your tag